# Is there a purpose for the cinderblocks?

Tags: dead-island

So far everything I have found in this game has had SOME purpose to it. Every item has a use, albeit sometimes it's hard to immediatly recognize. In ACT 2 (the village) I keep finding large cinderblocks, that can be held and otherwise placed much like explosive propane tanks, or stackable boxes. What are these cinderblocks for?

Comment: You can throw them at zombies (and other breakable objects, like windows and glass doors), but I wouldn't think the irritation of carrying one around would be worth the benefit.

Comment: @Agent86 if you are certain (source?) that is the only use for them post and I'll accept.

Comment: If I was 100% sure and had a source, I would have posted an answer :)  As it is, I think I'm still in Act 2 on this game, and there's not a lot of info around the net, sadly.

Comment: @Agent86 didn't seem to have a popular reception.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to being an awkward and clumsy weapon, the cinder blocks can be used to break certain environmental objects.

In particular, I believe there was at least one roof top with a skylight, where dropping a cinder block on the skylight would break it, allowing you to drop into the (locked and otherwise inaccessible) building below.

I believe there are far more of these cinder blocks available than practical problem-solving uses (that I discovered, at least).

Comment: can this be sourced?

Comment: @Ender unfortunately, I'm going entirely on memory from when I played it a fairly long time ago.  I'll try to search later tonight and see if I can find some references to back this up (I simply don't have time to dig out the game and try to replay it, however).

Comment: @Ender some quick searching shows multiple people mention smashing the sky light when retrieving the juice boxes from the gas station, but none of them mention cinder blocks (and I'm betting cinder blocks are not the only way to break the glass).

Comment: This agrees with what I remember as well.  Usually I found a bunch of them on ledges around town and tried to use them to hit zombies below me, but usually I'd just miss.

Comment: @Beofett that situation occurs in ACT 1, I'm referring to ACT 2. (the one with the juice boxes)